# Kafka consumer error handling offset reset

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using consuming events from kafka streams in a spring boot application version 2.4. The version of kafka client is 2.3.There are two consumers consuming the events. I want to put back the events back in kafka incase of any error. I Do NOT want to put the failed event in a dead letter queue. I am using ConsumerAwareListenerErrorHandler.

```
@Override
public Object handleError(Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException exception, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {

    ConsumerRecord record = (ConsumerRecord) message.getPayload();
    // consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()), record.offset());
    Collection collection = Arrays.asList(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()));
    consumer.seekToBeginning(collection);

    return null;
}
```

Now what I want is if I stop the consumer, The same error event should be consumed by the other running consumer. Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That won't work because any other records fetched by the previous `poll()` will still be processed; use a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` instead.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#seek-to-current